# How can I improve my Bomber cohort?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, optimization, rogue

So here's the general information about the character cohort that I have created.

The cohort, named Rat Fawkes, is a Rogue under the subclass "Bomber" at the level of 8 since my main character is actually level 10. With items and various feats, he's designed to be unhittable and very annoying. My DM allowed any feats and books to be used as long as they were published in some form or another, with no "homebrew" stuff. 3rd party material being okay.

More information about the character and his sheet can be found here: http://www.myth-weavers.com/sheet.html#id=940121

You could say this character is a parody or inspiration of Guy Fawkes. So the current build allows for a lot of interesting tricks and hits. Though he's ultimately low in the ac department, which is offset by the virtually high miss rate the enemies get. At the moment, the build is not set in stone so I am allowed to make changes when needed.

So what I wanted to ask: **Is there a way to optimize the character any further or improve him in a way to maximize his damage output, utility, and/or his feats without spending more gold, changing his class or changing his items?**

Comment: We still need to know what answers are to optimise *for*. What do you want to maximise? What is expendable? (The question needs to provide that because our Q&A format doesn't support leaving it up to answerer's opinions of what you “should” do.)

Comment: I want him to be a explosive expert while keeping to the class chosen. To handle large groups of enemies while keeping damage to himself and allies to a minimum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing for causing large damage with bombs would be to move some of your STR and/or DEX into INT (for more bombs per day) and invest in feats that allow you to use more bombs per round;

> If an alchemist has the Fast bombs discovery, can he use Rapid Shot, Two-Weapon Fighting, Improved Two-Weapon Fighting, haste, and similar abilities and effects to add more attacks?
>
> As written, yes, all of these apply because fast bombs "functions just like a full-attack with a ranged weapon."

[Ricochet Splash Weapon](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/general-feats/ricochet-splash-weapon) can also be useful if you're encountering clumps of enemies.

A note on the character concept, Guy Fawkes does not use a sling, he uses throwing daggers. I'd look into getting a couple Returning daggers +1 (or better as you prefer) and using TWF throwing weapons when you run out or want to save Bombs. I'm aware you said you didn't want to change items but... yeah. TWF Returning daggers is not the *best* build, but its definitely awesome to state 'I throw 5 daggers at them' in between the 'I drop 5 bombs dealing 6d6 each on them'.